# Check if a token exists inside database table - using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently trying to create a token, which a administrator can give to someone. This token needs to be entered in the registration page to verify that hes alowed to register a account.

My current migration file for the create_token_table looks like the following:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTokenTables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('token', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('token');
    }
}
```

This would create the table inside the database.

My register.blade file looks like the following:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Registrieren') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Namen eingeben.." required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Addresse') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="E-Mail eingeben.." required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Telefonnummer') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="phone" type="number" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" placeholder="Telefonnummer eingeben.." required>

                                @if ($errors->has('phone'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="charID" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Charackter ID') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="charID" type="number" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('charID') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="charID" value="{{ old('charID') }}" placeholder="Charackter ID eingeben.." required>

                                @if ($errors->has('charID'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('charID') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" placeholder="Passwort eingeben.." required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Passwort bestätigung eingeben.." required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="token" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Token') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="token" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('token') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="token" placeholder="Token eingeben.." required>

                                @if ($errors->has('token'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('token') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Registrieren') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

As you can see the user needs to add a token to the register form which should be checked when the user submits the form. As I think this should be done inside the **RegisterController.php** file, which looks like the following currently:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'phone' => 'required|integer',
            'charackerID' => 'required|integer',
            'token' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

How could I check if the user entered a valid token, which is stored inside the token database table?

Comment: Use the [exists rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-exists) e.g. `"token" => "exists:token,token"`

Comment: @apokryfos Avoid giving answers in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the validator function, you need `exists` validation rule:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'phone' => 'required|integer',
        'charackerID' => 'required|integer',
        'token' => 'required|string|exists:token,token',
    ]);
}
```

> My observation is that your table name and that column name 'token' looks potentially problematic, rather you can name your table tokens and then the column 'token'.

To understand more about validation, you definitely should make use of [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-exists)

Comment: Thank you for the help and explaination!